# Text Message (SMS)

Tags: android, sms

I want to send message from my app by just click on the button.Here is my code

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            String msg="your message";
            String numbers[]={"9560******","9560******"};
            System.out.println("test msg");
            sms.sendTextMessage(numbers[1],null,msg,null,null);
```

On clicking the button only test msg is printing on screen.sendTextMessage is not working.Message is not sending using this. No exception or error on logcat.

Please help me out.

Comment: You should define "not working" and provide any relevant error messages. For example, is your app crashing? Is the message simply not sending? Does smoke start coming out of your device? It's difficult to troubleshoot a problem without knowing what the problem is.

Comment: message is simply not sending. @NoChinDeluxe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I recomend you to put this on a `try{}catch{}` to know what's failing... check this :

```
try {      
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(numbers[1], null, msg, null, null);    
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent",
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (Exception ex) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.getMessage().toString(),
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

By the way don't forget to add this on your `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

If this doesn't work (**IT SHOULD**) take a look on this [`sms-messaging-android`](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/sms-messaging-android)

Comment: with this code doesn't work? try instead of puting `numbers[1]` try adding a number manually and let me know if it works.

Comment: What's saying? Nothing showing on the screen with my code?

Comment: It showing Message Sent. But it is not sending only showing.

Comment: And what you expect?

Comment: I expect to recieve msg on other mobile phone.

Comment: Do you have $$ to send it?And 3g?

Comment: Yeah I have $$. but not 3G

Comment: it should move in the outbox folder or sent message folder of the phone. But it is not.

Comment: Then maybe it's because you have not 3g... can you test it in other device that has 3g and coverage?

Comment: My phone has coverage and 3G enable

Comment: Can you test it with other device? (Number)